# iOS - Navigation bar - Inside table view with another navigation bar

Tags: ios, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

I'm having a navigation based application.
In the middle of my view I've a table view. On tapping a cell in table view only the views of the table view must be pushed. I'm thinking that if I have the tableview inside the navigation bar we can achieve this.
Is it possible to have tableview+nav bar inside a navigation based application?

Comment: Can I see some sort of illustration or something? I am having trouble understanding what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution [Navigation controller inside navigation controller](http://www.kickasslabs.com/2009/07/03/uinavigationcontroller-tricks/)